# Pipe to standard output in background

Tags: c, linux, pipe, message-queue

I have the following scheme:

```
\
 + granpa
    |
    +--- uncle
    |
    +--- dad
          |
          +--- son1
          +--- son2
          +--- son3
```

Uncle should be the only one controlling output, so I thought of using a `pipe()` created by *granpa* and shared with sons across *fork()*. So far so good.

The problem is that *uncle* also reads from a System V Message Queue (*msgget()*) in a infinite loop, hence acting as a server.

My problem is: in a scenario where we don't have multi-threading, how can these operations be done at the same time?

A couple of solutions that came to my mind include:

1. *dup*-ing pipe to standard output using `dup2()`, but it didn't work for unknown reasons; I guess it's because the kernel doesn't automatically copy data from pipe buffer to terminal output memory, that would be too cool.
2. Background copying data from pipe buffer with `splice()` or `tee()`, but it looks like they are all blocking and won't execute in background (or perhaps they do and I'm doing something wrong).
3. Using `select()` to determine at every cycle if I have a message or something to print, but unfortunately System V Message Queues aren't file descriptors in the Linux kernel (and I have no plans to make a custom version of the kernel as someone on the internet did exactly for this issue, absolutely).

Another bunch of solutions that could actually work but kinda break the logic are:

4. Using only a System V Message Queue with a very big struct and using the *msgtype* field to determine whether I'm asking for something or want to print something. Awful.
5. Insted of using a System V Message Queue, use a `socketpair()` and the do `select()` or `poll()` or whatever. This is my final solution, but if someone knows how to do it with System V Message Queues its preferred.

Comment: You wrote: _the kernel doesn't automatically copy data from pipe buffer to terminal output memory, that would be too cool._ If you were fine with automatic, uncontrolled copy from pipe to terminal, you'd give up the requirement _Uncle should be the only one controlling output_, wouldn't you? And without that requirement, why not let the sons' output go directly to terminal?

Comment: Good point, I guess I didn't realize that at the time. Anyway, I ended up using solution n. 5 and it worked without a glitch as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into the Linux [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus). It was met to simplify large multi piped projects like this and give the client program much less lines to work with.

Comment: Actually this is not going to be something great and widely used, so I think this is not necessary; but nevertheless thanks for poiting it out. My goal is to only have a POSIX-compilant kernel (or Linux, little different) and the C standard library as dependencies.